# listbox indexfrompoint does not return index

Tags: c#, winforms

I have coded the list box for drag n drop function. It is working fine when the initial part of item string is selected.

For e.g. I have `three entries in list box` like

1. hakuna matata jungle boy mogli - 9202
2. bam bam boom boombastic california - 9800
3. up up and away superman superman - 9808

When I mouse down till jungle, I get the `index as 0` or when I `click till boombastic` I get 1 but the property `returns -1` when I do mouse down anything after those letters.

Is there any defined length for item selection?

Here is my code:

```
lstBxJustAnother.Items.AddRange(new object[] 
  {"hakuna matata baloooo har har bole-9202",
   "bam bam boom california usa-9808",
   "up up and away superman 1940-9800"
  });

void lstBxJustAnother_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int itemIndex = lstBxJustAnother.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
  lblSecondSplit.Text = "Item" + itemIndex + " is selected";
  if (itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < lstBxJustAnother.Items.Count)
  {
    lstBxJustAnother.DoDragDrop(lstBxJustAnother.Items[itemIndex],
                                DragDropEffects.Move);
  }
  //MessageBox.Show(itemIndex.ToString());
}
```

I also tried using e.X,e.Y coordinates too.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: what are you doing so far?

Comment: It's not very clear where the issue is.  What does "mouse down till jungle" mean?